# Zsh: Make a certain set of aliases take precedence in completion suggestions

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have a couple of functions set in my zsh profile which let me save aliases to directories on the fly. It's pretty simple - just adds an alias to cd to the dir to a ~/.dirs file which gets sourced.

Is it possible in zsh to make aliases which come from this file take precedence in suggested tab completions?  For example, there's an alias in there called 'printeffect'.. If I type 'printe' and hit tab, the first completion suggestion is 'printenv'.. I want it to be 'printeffect'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

- an array holding your current special aliases, you only need to redefine the array when you switch dirs

  ```
  typeset -U MY_DIR_ALIASES
  MY_DIR_ALIASES=(foo1 foo2 foo3 foo-etc)
  ```
- a custom completer function `_foo` (file name is `_foo`) completing when the cursors in a `-commands-` position:

  ```
  _foo() {
    cmds=( $MY_DIR_ALIASES )
   _describe -commands- cmds
  }
  ```

  Or if you are saving this inside a file named `_foo`:

  ```
  #compdef -command-
  # -*-shell-script-*-
  cmds=( $MY_DIR_ALIASES )
  _describe -commands- cmds
  ```
- making this completer function be ran before any other:

  ```
  zstyle ':completion:::::' completer _foo _complete _approximate
  ```